# How do I edit someone else's tile?

Tags: manyland

I've spent some time creating and editing my own tiles in Manyland.

I know you can easily "fork" a tile that you have created by dragging it onto <kbd>+ create</kbd>.

But when I've tried doing the same thing to tiles I've collected from other people, I just get a blank canvas.

**Is there any way I can fork tiles I've collected from other people?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "clone" a tile, you need to have a high enough rank to make the item type yourself (Rank 3 to make a moving item, rank 5 to make a harmful one ect.) and the item itself needs to be marked as "clonable".

Sadly as this flag is not marked by default most items aren't clonable.

To check if an item is marked as clonable right click on the item to see its details, and look for the "clonable" tag:

[image: clonable tag]